# How to access request parameter programmatic lly in ADF

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I have a requirement where i want to access request paremeter(sent as HTTP post /Get) programitally inside a managed bean which is running under ADF context.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The external context gives you access to request parameters but with ADF Faces there may be multiple requests sent when a page renders. So best is to define a phaseListener (f:view afterMethod) on the page and listen for RESTORE_VIEW. Then check for the request parameter and save it in a managed bean that is in a scope larger than request (viewScope would be best). This way for as long as a page is active you can access its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you access the request scope programmatically from the ExternalContext. To get the external context:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
```

From the ExternalContext, you can access the various Request based information(header, parameters, etc.)

Now, the question is how did you make the request since when using ADF one does not normally construct HTTP post/get requests manually?